# If some error ocur in transaction 2 what will happen? Does the exec will stop and rollbacks all trans and will no exec transaction 3

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my case I want to stop exec of any further executions on all other nested transactions. 
If there is an error in tran1 or tran 2 execution should stop and throw error an rollback all previous changes made.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;


BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION 1
  Insert into Table1 Values (.....)
  Delete from Table2 
  --
  --other example code
  --
COMMIT TRANSACTION 1

BEGIN TRANSACTION 2

  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Table2]
  WHILE 1=1

    BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'

    DELETE TOP (1000) ufb 
    FROM Table1 ufb 
    INNER JOIN Table2 mbss on mbss.ID=ufb.ID 
   -- 
    IF @@ROWCOUNT < 1 BREAK 
    END
    --other example code
COMMIT TRANSACTION 2

BEGIN TRANSACTION 3

    --Some insert code
    --other example code
COMMIT TRANSACTION 3

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRAN
   DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE()
   DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY()
   DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE()
   RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 
           @ErrorSeverity, 
           @ErrorState 
           );
           END CATCH
```

Comment: if you want to roll back *everything* you need to put them all in one tranasction, not separate ones. You can'#t roll back transaction 1 when tranasction 2 fails; especially when transaction 1 has already been committed.

Comment: I ve try it but I am getting error "Cannot disable or enable constraint " . That's why I was thinking that this will work.

Comment: [Can I change table structure in a transaction and then roll it back if there is an error?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24883/can-i-change-table-structure-in-a-transaction-and-then-roll-it-back-if-there-is) may offer some clues about mixing DDL and DML in a transaction.